# How to delete something from a SQL table through a webpage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm just look for the simple way to delete something from my SQL table through my webpage.
I'm using ASP in visual studio, I have the database connection working but I need some help the code to actually remove something from the table.

```
alter procedure [dbo].[spEmployeeHolidays] (@UserID int)
as
select  Holidays.HolidayStartDate,
Holidays.HolidayEndDate,
Holidays.Duration,
Holidays.Status,
Holidays.Description,
Holidays.ID
from Holidays
Where @UserID = Holidays.EmployeeID
```

Comment: please share the code

Comment: Why not just post your code in the first place?

Comment: Because I had some problems with putting it on here

Comment: Indent four spaces paste your code.

Comment: To avoid all the different SQL syntax answers I suggest you tag your question with what SQL database you are using, my guess would be [tag:SQL-Server] judging by your proc, maybe even include the SQL server version tag as well ([tag:sql-server-2005], [tag:sql-server-2008], [tag:sql-server-2012] you get the idea).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query to delete elements in a table

```
 DELETE FROM table_name
 WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

If you want to delete all the elements in a table , then you should use

```
 DELETE * FROM table_name;
```

Or you can use the update query to change the value as follows

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally to delete from a table you do:

```sql
DELETE FROM [table name]
WHERE [col] = <value>
```